# Can't get highcharts export server working using Java

Tags: highcharts

everyone,

I followed instructions on [highcharts export server](http://docs.highcharts.com/#export-server-setup). And my test environment is Ubuntu Server, tomcat 7.x, java 1.7.x, the latest highcharts export server code cloned by git. No problem occurred during mvn install and mvn clean package. And soem settings of my app-convert.properties is

```
port=8080 # the same port with my tomcat
exec = /home/{my user name}/phantomjs-1.9.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```

And from the logs of Tomcat, I can see that phantomjs is started and listening on port 8080. Also when I access http://{myservername}:8080/highchars-export-web/, it's loaded correctly, even when I click 'Generate Image' button, it gave me a file named 'Charts.png'. However, the image's size is 1kb, not the one as getting from http://export.highcharts.com/demo. I don't know what I am missing. I need you guys help on this.

Best wishes,

Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a different port other than the one your tomcat (or other service) is listening on. That port you set in the app.properties files is for the phatomjs service to listen on.

Comment: Cool. I changed the port to 7777, then it worked. But I remembered that the first attempt is using 7777, but it failed with 'Timeout bala bala'. And now it seems it's has nothing to do with Batik now.